# How to call a TYPO3 custom viewhelper from a typoscript (.ts) file and receive a response from viewhelper?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I tried to call a custom viewhelper in TYPO3 9.5.9 from a typoscript file. But it is not working.
An example for viewhelper is given below:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\BlogExample\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

class GravatarViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
   use CompileWithRenderStatic;

   public static function renderStatic(
       array $arguments,
       \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
       RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
   ) {
       return 'World';
   }
}
```

How can I call this custom viewhelper from a typoscript (.ts) file and get a response ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you extract the function that "does what the ViewHelper does" to a separate method and make it possible to call this method as a public method, and make it receive the PHP function arguments it requires (user email address, for example) *wrapped in an `array $parameters`.

This method can then be called from the ViewHelper as well as from TypoScript. The TypoScript would be something like:

```
lib.myGravatarObject = USER
lib.myGravatarObject.userFunc = MyVendor\ExtensionName\GravatarRenderer
lib.myGravatarObject.userEmail = foo@bar.com
```

If you name the properties of the `array $parameters` the same as your ViewHelper arguments you can simply pass `$this->arguments` or `$arguments` from within the ViewHelper (the former if you are implementing `render()`, the latter if you are implementing `renderStatic()`). It also makes it more transparent that you use the same property names in TS as you would use for ViewHelper arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject with a minimal template (e.g. via template property):

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
   template.cObject = TEXT
   template.cObject.value(
      <html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:mv="http://typo3.org/ns/MyVendor/BlogExample/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
      <mv:GravatarViewHelper />
   )
}
```

It seems to be possible. But as Bernd already asked: Why would one do that?

Comment: ok, I want to pass a string to the php function and receive another string as response. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why should you do this? (please describe your use case)

Viewhelpers are for usage in FLUID templates, there you have the correct and matching context.

If you want to call a PHP function inside of typoscript directly you have the option of an `userfunc` ([manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html)). But you need to provide the necssary context.

Comment: ok. I want to pass a string to the php function and receive another string as response. Thank you